# Install wordpress using amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-rds

Now this is weird!

I am trying to install a WordPress website on a Amazon EC2 server with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and [amazon RDS][1] database service.

I have installed apache and wphp and ran the required tests (again and again actually) if something is wrong there.

But when I go to the root of WordPress folder (also the root of the server i .e. folder "www") I get this error

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

Yes this is pretty obvious because I don't want to install MySQL on my system.

The funny thing is I tried searching it online and there are examples of tons of WordPress websites running on RDS and I couldnt find a single page with this issue.

Any solutions/suggestions?

Is is that i'll have to install MySQL on my system even though I don't want to use it . Doesn't it skip the whole point?

Thanks in advance

Edit : I didn't even reach create configuration file page. The index.php file pretty much showed this error and nothing else.

here is the tutorial i was following : http://www.slideshare.net/mrjain/installing-wordpress-on-aws
check out slide 16 it never mentions installing mysql

Comment: Where are you expecting the data to be stored since you `don't want to install mysql`?  Did you have another mysql server somewhere?  Where you thinking you could use sqlite?  Were you expecting it to magically just handled by the cloud fairies?

Comment: not fairies actually but this.
http://www.slideshare.net/mrjain/installing-wordpress-on-aws.
slide 16.
they did it on amazon linux ami but for ubuntu it coundnt have been much different ! thats for your constructive comment though !

Comment: @Zoredache Amazon RDS is a managed MySQL installation. Amazon handles running the database. Basically, this is a question about setting up WordPress with a database on a different server than the WordPress install, which is quite common for scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install MySQL **server**, but you do need the client-side stuff for PHP.

`apt-get install php5-mysql` should do the trick.

Comment: it says invalid opertation php5-mysql
even tried with sudo in front same thing (sorry if i am sounding like a noob i am just a linux beginner)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the important bit, `install`! Fixed!

Comment: it installed correctly but the solution didnt work thanks for the response though!

Comment: You may need to reboot your web server after installing this.

Comment: and if that doesn't do the trick, try `apt-get install mysql-client` and another Apache reboot too.

Comment: i used this to uninstall any previous mysql components 
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client mysql-server . 
then i ran the command specified in the andswer that is apt-get install php5-mysql .
then i restarted apache using this /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
and now its working .
P.S. there is no mysql server installed :) time to bring the RDS onboard !

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the php-mysql part of the binary.

```
yum install php-mysql php-pdo
```

you might want to look for any other pecls you might be missing,

```
yum search php
```

Comment: He said it's an Ubuntu system.

Comment: sorry did miss that bit. altho ubuntu has a similar setup in the pecls each being different packages to be added. [amazons own linux is based on ubuntu with yum added in for some weird reason.]

Comment: well this was the same solution as the the one i marked the answer . but he gave the correct code . Thank You For The Response Though!:)

Answer (score 0):

You must install MySQL client for WordPress:
http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Comment: Yes, but you don't necessarily need the **server** installed on the **same** machine the PHP's installed on.

Comment: agreed with @ceejayoz on this ! THank You for response though !